# unable to load image in xamarin forms

Tags: image, xamarin

code is - in xamarin -

in code behind
var image = new Image { Source = "//Assets//food.jpg" };

image is not loadind in actual xamarin form.

Comment: code in xamarin for image -

Comment: <StackLayout>
            <Image Source="/Assets/food.jpg" IsVisible="true" AnchorX="500" AnchorY="500" IsEnabled="True" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"></Image>
            </StackLayout>

Comment: this is not working

Answer (score 0):

from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#local-images)

> Android - Place images in the Resources/drawable directory with Build
> Action: AndroidResource. High- and low-DPI versions of an image can
> also be supplied (in appropriately named Resources subdirectories such
> as drawable-ldpi, drawable-hdpi, and drawable-xhdpi).

Answer (score 0):

From document [Images in Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#local-images),we know that there are several methods to display images in xamarin.

**1.Local images**

Image files can be added to each application project and referenced from Xamarin.Forms shared code. This method of distributing images is required when images are platform-specific, such as when using different resolutions on different platforms, or slightly different designs.

In code is:

```
 <Image Source="waterfront.jpg" />
```

Or

```
 var image = new Image { Source = "waterfront.jpg" };
```

Note:

We should put images into correct folder, in android ,we should put image to  folder `drawables`.

> To use the same image filename across all platforms the name must be
> valid on all platforms. Android `drawables` have naming restrictions –
> only `lowercase` letters, numbers, underscore, and period are allowed –
> and for cross-platform compatibility this must be followed on all the
> other platforms too. The example filename waterfront.png follows the
> rules, but examples of invalid filenames include "water front.png",
> "WaterFront.png", "water-front.png", and "wåterfront.png".

**2.Embedded images**

Embedded images are also shipped with an application (like local images) but instead of having a copy of the image in each application's file structure the image file is embedded in the assembly as a resource. This method of distributing images is recommended when identical images are used on each platform, and is particularly suited to creating components, as the image is bundled with the code.

To embed an image in a project, right-click to add new items and select the image/s you wish to add. By default the image will have `Build Action: None`; this needs to be set to `Build Action: EmbeddedResource`

If you place embedded images into folders within your project, the folder names are also separated by periods (.) in the resource ID. Moving the beach.jpg image into a folder called `MyImages` would result in a resource ID of `WorkingWithImages.MyImages.beach.jpg`.

Sample code:

```
   Image embeddedImage = new Image
{
    Source = ImageSource.FromResource("WorkingWithImages.beach.jpg", typeof(MyClass).GetTypeInfo().Assembly)
};
```

For more, you can check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#local-images

And there is a whole sample included in above document, you can check it up here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/workingwithimages/ .

**Update:**

In UWP, by default, images should be placed in the application's root directory with `Build Action: Content`. Alternatively, images can be placed in a different directory which is then specified with a platform-specific.

You can refer to the sample code in uwp here: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/main/WorkingWithImages/WorkingWithImages.UWP .

For more information, see [Default image directory on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/windows/default-image-directory).

Comment: i have three projects ios android and windows forms in xamarin which folder shud i select to put folder for images.

your soln is not working.

Comment: i need for the xamarin forms right now not ios android letter for android ios.

Comment: Depending on your actual needs, we may need to put images in different folders. Are your images on different platforms showing the same image?

Comment: right now iam trying for windows xamarin only which folder do i need for windows xamarin.

Comment: Hi anybody can halp for windows xamarin forms.

Comment: Do you mean in xamarin uwp, right? Then you can check up  my updated answer at the bottom of my reply.